# In what points of the same X coordinate will the tangents to the curves given be parallel

Tags: analytic-geometry

Hoping someone could help me.

In what points of the same X coordinate ( different from 0 ) will the tangents to the curves be parallel?

$ y = x^3 $ and $ y = x^2$

I know two lines are parallel if their slopes are equal. Also I know that a curve slope is it's derrivative so basically: $m1=3x^2$ and $m2=2x$. Should I just simply set these equal to each other and find out my X is $\frac{2}{3}$ ?

Comment: yes. the point is at $x = \frac 23$ and the slope of both lines will be $\frac 43$.